# Evaluate associative php array inline

Tags: php, arrays, eval

I am retrieving the f-number from JPEG images by EXIF data. To get the desired number, I need to evaluate the expression. Right now I use three lines of code for this. Could it be made shorter, or ideally as a one-liner?

```
$fnumber = $exif['FNumber'];
eval("\$fnumber = $fnumber;");
$photo['fnumber'] = $fnumber;
```

Relevant content from var_export($exif):

```
'FileName' => '_80A9888.jpg',
'FileSize' => 487519,
'FileType' => 2,
'MimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
'ExposureTime' => '1/30',
'FNumber' => '4/1',
'ExposureProgram' => 3,
'ISOSpeedRatings' => 125,
'ExifVersion' => '0230',
'ShutterSpeedValue' => '4906891/1000000',
'ApertureValue' => '4/1',
'ExposureBiasValue' => '-1/3',
'MaxApertureValue' => '4/1',
'MeteringMode' => 3,
'Flash' => 16,
'FocalLength' => '70/1',
```

Comment: please, provide `var_export` of `$exif`

Comment: Next time you think you need to use `eval` stop (, throw away the code that uses eval) and rethink everything :-)

Comment: So it is not only in Javascript eval is evil! This code won't be available online—though I guess they all say that, until one day it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is very risky. Code can be injected from an input source (the jpeg).

**!!! Don't use `eval()` here. !!!**

You'll need to write a little parser which evaluates the expression:

```
// Typical value of fnumber (I obtained from a test JPEG using exif_read_data())
$fnumber = '35/10';
// Split by `/`
$operands = explode('/', $fnumber);
// Divide 
$result = $operands[0] / $operands[1];

echo $result;
```

Comment: So you think that verbosity is the better choice here? I was hoping I could make it *shorter* somehow.

Comment: @HenrikHelmers Definitely. If you want a one-liner wrap the calculation in a function.